# How does one place the tag R on the ignore list?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I observe that entering R in the box, yields other tags, containing R, but R itself does not show.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but... can't you just hit "Add" after typing R and forget about the dropdown?

Comment: lol.  i didn't think of that.

Comment: Pop that in as an answer, and i'll accept it.

Comment: You can also hit escape to dismiss the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dropdown is unnecessary to use when adding an ignored tag. Just enter "R" in the field, and hit the "Add" button, and it'll be complete.