# Please add exact tag matches to the autocomplete lists

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, autocomplete

Short tags that are substrings of other tags are difficult to find in autocomplete lists. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64125/how-does-one-place-the-tag-r-on-the-ignore-list) is a recent example of a user having problems with this.

Putting an exact text input match to the top of the list is already implemented on the [tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page:

[image]

but not in any autocomplete list.

---

Interesting/ignored tags:

[image]

---

Ask Question/edit page:

[image]

---

To make it easier to find short tags, I would like the same behaviour from the tag search page implemented in the autocomplete lists.

**EDIT:** Sorry for the misunderstanding. I realize the autocomplete lists order descending by popularity and the search page orders by name. I think that part should stay the same. All I want is the exact match functionality added to the autocomplete lists.

Comment: I would like the exact tag match to be available on auto-complete as you request, but I'd prefer the rest of the behavior be kept the unchanged. Tag page is listed in something alphabetical, while the auto-complete is done by volume, and I think that the metric in the latter is useful for it.

Comment: @Grace: Good idea, but you can do both (keep shown items in popularity order plus show exact match) by bumping the last item if the exact match is lower.

Comment: @Gnome That's exactly the solution I would like.

Comment: Yeah, sorry guys. I've updated my post. @Grace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it up, will be deployed later today