# Tag autosuggestion is broken for tags that contain hyphens

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, autocomplete

This may be a byproduct of [the change made here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64130/please-add-exact-tag-matches-to-the-autocomplete-lists). In fact, given my example, it seems that change does not completely work.

[image]

Another use case: here on Meta, try entering 'specific-q' ([specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question)) and try to open the dropdown — apparently there are no suggestions.

Comment: This sets a new standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Ok, I backed out this change for now.</strike>

Fixed it