# Autocomplete suggested tags don't consistently autocomplete tags that should be suggested.... they seem to remember some autocomplete removals?

Tags: bug, tags, tag-autocomplete

I first noticed this issue on RPG.SE, and have been trying to reproduce it here

Here typing 'tag' doesn't suggest 'tags', however that might be because the space or hyphen character is considered earlier alphabetically? However some of the matches contain the word 'tags'

[image: suggested tags for this question. The tag 'bug' is completed, and the word 'tag' has been typed, but 'tags' has not been suggested]

After typing an 's' to makes 'tags', it's now suggested along with others. Perhaps this is expected behaviour?

[image: amended suggested tags for this question. The 'bug' tag remains, but now the word 'tags' has been typed and is now suggested.]

However on RPG.SE where I first saw this, the word combat wouldn't be suggested at all:

[image: previously combat would not be suggested even after typing]

Trying to reproduce it, by adding a similar set of tags, and typing 'social'

[image: the word 'social' has been typed and that tag is suggested along with others]

Adding 'dnd-5e' doesn't seem to change it

[image: as above but with the tag 'dnd-5e' before it, social is still suggested.]

The 'combat' tag is still not suggested:

[image: the word 'combat' has replaced 'social', but the tag for 'combat' has not been suggested]

After refreshing the page, it is now suggested

[image: The page was refreshed, and the word combat typed in, now that tag is suggested]

Trying with a tag in front:

[image: dnd-5e and combat is suggested]

Reproducing it somehow:

Social has decided not to be social:

[image: social is not suggested with other tags present, social-stats is suggested]

Adding and removing tags seems to remember, and not re-suggest:

[image: removing social-combat and replacing it with social-stats, and now social-combat is not suggested]

[image: removing social, and social-combat and social-stats now means none of them are suggested except another tag]

If you remove that last tag for 'shock-social-science-fiction', and retype social, now there are no suggestions

[image: remove that last tag for 'shock-social-science-fiction', and retype social, now no suggestions]

Even by itself:

[image: social word typed by itself with no suggestions]

It seems like you can also reproduce it by deleting one tag via the keyboard, while editing another:

[image: combat on it's own after having the tag mounted-combat deleted via keyboard]

[image: 'moun' does not suggest 'mount' while 'mounted-combat' is a tag]

But sometimes fully completing the word does bring that suggestion back?

[image: 'mount' now suggests the tag 'mount']

Overall I'm not clear on what is determining whether a tag is autocomplete suggested, but it feels  inconsistent and buggy?

Apologies for the figurative tonne of screenshots, I'm not sure how  best to suggest these otherwise....

What's going on and can this be fixed?

p.s. Now I've got suggested-tags missing when I type in 'tags'... ‍♂️ It's not in my initial screenshot, but there's definitely room for it now but other tags of the for 'X-tags' are. Typing 'suggested' does work.

[image: suggested-tags was removed, and doesn't want to be re-suggested by typing 'tags']

Comment: exact matches *should* get an auto-complete suggestion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64130/175002

Comment: Under the hood it is calling https://meta.stackexchange.com/filter/tags?q=tag&newstyle=true where you can vary the q=tag to test various responses for partial or exact matched tagnames. That is maybe easier to collect enough data to form an idea what is going on.

Comment: @rene So I did have a peek at the network tab  *partway through* and I didn't see any calls at all. I'm guessing some caching is happening? [Maybe that's at fault?](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Did anybody manage to reproduce this?