# Can't add certain tag groups to tag sets

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, tag-filters

A bug arising from a UI snafu: if you enter a tag, and it is less popular than six other tags that it is a substring of, then it doesn't appear in the pop-up menu, and you can't add it to your tag set.

E.g., when I try entering [tex], the menu offers get "text", "latex" and four other tag names with "text" as a substring, but not "tex".

There might be a workaround for this, but I haven't figured it out.  I propose changing the scoring mechanism so that exact matches are weighted highest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We modified the tag-autocomplete logic so the exact match always shows up if it exists.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually possible to accomplish in the current system. When you type out "tex", instead of hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> or anything, just click off of the dropdown.

[image]

It'll give you the stats for the **[tex]** tag and let you add it properly. This is similar to [the same scenario with tag preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64125/how-does-one-place-the-tag-r-on-the-ignore-list).

Even with the capability, though, I agree that exact matches should be provided in the dropdown. Here's a related proposal for this on all manner of tag dropdowns on the Q&A sites themselves: [Please add exact tag matches to the autocomplete lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64130/please-add-exact-tag-matches-to-the-autocomplete-lists). I don't know if the mechanisms are identical, but doing both at the same time would be swell.

Comment: Yes, that works and the link to the [feature-request] is spot on.